# Xorg: Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, xrandr

Last week I received a new notebook in my work and everything is fine, except my dual-head setup(was flawless in the old model). My goal is to have **one screen in each monitor**, but instead I'm getting **one screen "stretched" between two monitors**. I'm using the *exact* configuration of the old model, but the end result is totally different. Any ideas?

Note that the Xorg log shows the following error:

```
[  3779.739] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

If I comment the *Screen* line of both *Device* sections, the error goes away, but nothing changes.

**Relevant information on the links below:**

- Xorg log: http://pastebin.com/LQszqwke
- Xorg configuration: http://pastebin.com/rtgmBwz1
- LSPCI Output: http://pastebin.com/s32ZCRNh
- xrandr -q: http://pastebin.com/qp4y9iiN

Comment: Are you on a nvidia-based card ?

Comment: No, an Intel one (as in lspci)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you herited an old nvidia-based X.org configuration file, with Twinview & Xinerama.

- TwinView is Nvidia specific, it won't work with an intel one.
- Xinerama is probably the option causing the "stretch effect" you observe

Nowadays, X.org is dynamic and graphically configurable. You can just delete your old xorg.conf and graphically configure it the way you want it with gnome or kde system tool.

Comment: I removed both the Xinerama clause and the TwinView: the "stretch effect" is no more and everything is working as expected. The error line in the log is still present, but since it isn't affecting my setup, I will mark this answer as correct.

Thanks!